# Blocking all users without referrer BUT allowing Googlebot/bingbot at the same time (with .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, setenv

Because of some amateur-made DDOS attack on my website, I had to deny some traffic with .htaccess which worked fine.

Unfortunately, it also blocks the googlebot/bingbot:

```
order allow, deny
deny from 54.

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

It simply block whole traffic from `54.x.x.x` (only traffic I get from it is from infected amazon cloud - I know I could exclude just 30 IPs ranges for amazon cloud and not the whole `54.x.x.x` but I was in a need of fast solution).

The rest of bots (most of them from China, Taiwan and so on) don't use referrer, so:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" bad_user
```

blocks them all.

But it also have a **side effects**:

1. When somebody visit my page from bookmark or when he type it directly to the browser (e.g. he has red it on business card), he won't see my website.
2. Googlebot, bingbot (as well as other less important bots) usually don't use referrer either.

`#1` is an inconvenience, but `#2` is a real problem I have to solve quickly.

I've found that bots important for me use those labels:

```
66.249.64.119 - - [...] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 403 534 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.64.119 - - [...] "GET /programowanie/ HTTP/1.1" 403 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.64.115 - - [...] "GET /3d-graphic/ HTTP/1.1" 403 535 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

207.46.13.4 - - [...] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 403 534 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
207.46.13.4 - - [...] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 524 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
```

Is it possible in `.htaccess` to somehow merge my rules with **"but if label contains "Googlebot" or "bingbot", let him go"** as the most important one (even if they don't use referrer)?

If not, maybe I can add something to `robots.txt` to inform Google/Bing that they should have put referrer in their labels (I doubt they would take it into account)?

Comment: Why don't you simply want to block the malicious traffic?

Comment: @MichaelHampton What you mean by that? I guess that yes, I simply do want to block bad traffic. But no, it's not so simple to do so. The traffic that I get is about 10-20GB/day from small DDOS attack, with about 1000 different IPs from 7 countries. They come either from amazon cloud (some infected resources) or one of those countries (IPs range for China is more then 40k lines to .htaccess) but if so, they don't use referrer (amazon cloud uses google as referrer).

Comment: @PolGraphic Michael means use a firewall, rather than blocking at the application level... Investigate `iptables` and `ipset`

Comment: @HBruijn I see, but the website is on paid hosting for which I don't have direct access to firewall. I also guess that many other people are in the same situation. They use web hosting providers (which are cheaper and ok for most cases) instead of setting up own machines / pay for virtual servers just to do something that can be partly achieved with htaccess. Still, I agree - if I would be able to configure firewall on server - that's the best solution (but not always possible without additional costs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some solution for `#2`:

```
order deny,allow
deny from 54.

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm" good_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "http://www.google.com/bot.html" good_user
Deny from env=bad_user
Allow from env=good_user
```

Note the `order deny, allow` - thanks to it it will work that way:

1. Block all traffic from `54.x.x.x`. Also block all traffic without referrer.
2. Then, unblock the traffic for the request that contains either `http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm` or `http://www.google.com/bot.html`.

Anyway, **I will wait for other answers**, because I'm not sure if it's optimal solution for `#2`.

**And I still did not manage to solve `#1`.**

So if you want to:

> block all users without referrer BUT allow Googlebot/bingbot at the
>   same time

you can just use my code for `.htaccess` without `deny from 54.` and `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_user` lines, which are specific for my case (ddos).